# failure to receive a hidden sub-menu in nav bar

Tags: html, css

I want to create a horizontal drop-down menu. However, when I use `nav li:hover > ul` to retrieve the sub-menu after successfully hiding it with `display:none`, the sub-menu just disappears entirely. How can I make the sub-menu appear again when mouse hovers on "Collection" button? appreciate your help.

HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Princess.css"> 
        <title> PPRINCESS </title> 
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="wrap"> 
            <div id="title">
                <h1> PPRINCESS </h1>
            </div>
                <ul id="bar">
                    <li> <a href="home.html" > Home </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="collection.html" > Collection </a> </li>
                            <ul>
                                <li>  <a href="angels.html"> Angel on Meadows </a> </li>
                                <li>  <a href="beach.html"> Beachy Ladies </a> </li>
                                <li>  <a href="streets.html"> Pavements and Streets </a> </li>
                                <li>  <a href="symbol.html"> Become a Symbol </a> </li>
                            </ul>
                    <li> <a href "shoes.html" > Shoes </a> </li>
                </ul>
        </div>

    </body> 

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #ffcda0;
}
#wrap {
    width: 1000px; 
    background-color: #ffff66;
}

#title {
    width:250px;
    padding:20px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;

    /* text-color: #525252;*/
}
#bar { 
    background-color: #fefbf7;
    width: 650px;  
    float: right;
    list-style:none; 
    padding: 20px;  
    display:inline-block ; 
}

#bar li {
    float:left;
    background-color: #fefbf7;
} 

#bar li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;  
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #4c4c4c;
} 
#bar li:hover {
    background-color:beige;
}
#bar li a,visited {
    color: moccasin;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
#bar ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
}

#bar li:hover > ul li{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: What happened?  why you removed ratings from my answer, let me know if the issue was not addressed with the resolution that I provided. Thanks

Comment: no I think I was messing with the site and accidentally removed yours. T_T I put it back. sorry!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction of your code. Though, you'll need to apply more css to make the 1st sub menu looks good.

```css
body {
    background-color: #ffcda0;
}

#wrap {
    width: 1000px; 
    background-color: #ffff66;
}

#title {
    width:250px;
    padding:20px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;

    /* text-color: #525252;*/
}
#bar { 
    background-color: #fefbf7;
    width: 650px;  
    float: right;
    list-style:none; 
    padding: 20px;  
    display:inline-block ; 
}

#bar li {
    float:left;
    background-color: #fefbf7;
} 

#bar li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;  
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #4c4c4c;
} 
#bar li:hover {
    background-color:beige;
}
#bar li a,visited {
    color: moccasin;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
#bar ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
}

#bar li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
        <div id="wrap"> 
            <div id="title">
                <h1> PPRINCESS </h1>
            </div>
                <ul id="bar">
                    <li> <a href="home.html" > Home </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="collection.html" > Collection </a> 
                            <ul>
                                <li>  <a href="angels.html"> Angel on Meadows </a> </li>
                                <li>  <a href="beach.html"> Beachy Ladies </a> </li>
                                <li>  <a href="streets.html"> Pavements and Streets </a> </li>
                                <li>  <a href="symbol.html"> Become a Symbol </a> </li>
                            </ul>
                      </li>
                    <li> <a href "shoes.html" > Shoes </a> </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
```

Also, you can look at this answer for a better menu - [How to make menu bar with nested submenu css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892059/how-to-make-menu-bar-with-nested-submenu-css/32893378#32893378)

Answer (score 0):

Its working well, please try this code. hope this will resolve your issue.

```
        <div id="wrap"> 
            <div id="title">
                <h1> PPRINCESS </h1>
            </div>
                <ul id="bar">
                    <li> <a href="home.html" > Home </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="collection.html" > Collection </a> 
                            <ul>
                                <li>  <a href="angels.html"> Angel on Meadows </a> </li>
                                <li>  <a href="beach.html"> Beachy Ladies </a> </li>
                                <li>  <a href="streets.html"> Pavements and Streets </a> </li>
                                <li>  <a href="symbol.html"> Become a Symbol </a> </li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href "shoes.html" > Shoes </a> </li>
                </ul>
        </div>

    </body> 

</html>

<style>
body {
    background-color: #ffcda0;
}
#wrap {
    width: 1000px; 
    background-color: #ffff66;
}

#title {
    width:250px;
    padding:20px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;

    /* text-color: #525252;*/
}
#bar { 
    background-color: #fefbf7;
    width: 650px;  
    float: right;
    list-style:none; 
    padding: 20px;  
    display:inline-block ; 
}

#bar li {
    float:left;
    background-color: #fefbf7;
} 

#bar li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;  
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #4c4c4c;
} 
#bar li:hover {
    background-color:beige;
}
#bar li a,visited {
    color: moccasin;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
#bar ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
}

#bar li:hover  ul{
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi CreativePS and Xahed Kamal, thanks so much for your help. I looks at the code and it seems the only thing changed is the last line: #bar li:hover  ul{
    display:block;  is it correct? I changed the last line in my code but it doesn't look like the issue is resolved. could you pls help point out the issue in the original code? thanks!

Comment: Change last line in css to 

#bar li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}

and move the <ul></ul> of submenu inside <li></li>


Then it will work

Answer (score 0):

**Change last line in css to**

```
#bar li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
```

and move the `<ul></ul>` of submenu inside `<li></li>`

Then it will work