# what is the css to add a submenu to my navbar?

Tags: html, css

The following html code is for a navbar.  I have some commented out code here that I want to be a submenu for the "Adhesives" menu item.  I placed that submenu list between the "a" tag of "Adhesives".  I'm not sure if that is correct placement for that list to be a submenu.  What is the CSS to make that list a submenu of "Adhesives"?  Also, I know that I'm not using  class=....  in the tags.  If I stay with the convention I'm using here (without class=....) what would the css be?  If I were to use class=.... in the tags how would that change the css?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Alt-Web Demos :: Multi-colored Drop Menu</title>
    <style>
        body { font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

        /* BEGIN HORIZONTAL DROP-MENU */
        nav {
            position: relative;
            width: 600px;  /**adjust width as needed**/
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
            background:#CFF;
        }

        nav ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }

        nav li {
            list-style: none;
            font-size: 12px;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
        }

        /**top level menu**/
        nav li a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-right: 12px; /* space between links */
            width: 9em; /* adjust as needed or use auto */
            padding: 8px;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 1.50em;
            border: 1px dotted #666;
            border-top: none;
            color:#000;
        }

        /**alternating background colors**/
        nav li:nth-child(odd) > a { background: #CAD3D3}
        nav li:nth-child(even) > a { background: #9BBB59}

        /**top menu style on mouse over**/
        nav li:hover > a{
            color: #FFF;
            background: #004A43;
        }

        /**sub-menu**/
        nav li ul {
            display: none;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 1em;
            background: none;
        }

        /**sub-menu, help for older IE**/
        nav li:hover ul, nav li.hover ul {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav li:hover li, nav li.hover li { float: none; }

        /**drop-menu style**/
        nav li:hover li a, nav li.hover li a {
            width: 9em; /* adjust width as needed or use auto */
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        /**drop-menu style on mouse over**/
        nav li li a:hover {
            background:#D3E1B7;
            color: #004A43;
        }

        /* Clear floated elements at the end*/
        nav:after {
            visibility: hidden;
            display: block;
            font-size: 0;
            content: " ";
            clear: both;
            height: 0;
        }
        /**end Horizontal drop-menus**/
    </style>
</head>

<body class="demos">
    <div id="content">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="first" href="#">ABOUT US &#9660;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS &#9660;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Broken Glass</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mosaic Tiles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Adhesives &#9658;
                            <!--<ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sticky</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Stickier</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Stickiest</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hella Sticky</a></li>
                            </ul>-->
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Grout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES &#9660;</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Gloves</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rubber Mallets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sponges</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Safety Glasses</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </nav>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, learn to use a snippet, or jsFiddle, so that people can help you easier on SO.  Second, if you learn to use [descendant selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors), it will set you free on this sort of styling issue.  Using descendant selectors, you could simply change your "sub menus" code to `nav li:hover > ul { display: block; ....}`, which says "when you hover an LI, only show the immediate child UL...."

Comment: I think that this is what you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892059/how-to-make-menu-bar-with-nested-submenu-css?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Yes, I do need to learn how to use jsFiddle.  I have been going there quite a bit lately.  Could you suggest like a tutorial or such for learning how to use jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to nest the submenu in an `li`, not in the `a`. Then you need to change your selector for showing nested `ul`'s to use the direct decendent selector `li:hover > ul { display: block; }` so that you don't show *all* submenus in an `li` when you hover over one. Then if you want it to expand out to the right, use `left: calc(100% - 12px); top: 0;` on the double nested menus, and `calc()` is to account for the horizontal margin you have on the links in an `li`.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Alt-Web Demos :: Multi-colored Drop Menu</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    /* BEGIN HORIZONTAL DROP-MENU */
    
    nav {
      position: relative;
      width: 600px;
      /**adjust width as needed**/
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
      background: #CFF;
    }
    
    nav ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0
    }
    
    nav li {
      list-style: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    /**top level menu**/
    
    nav li a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin-right: 12px;
      /* space between links */
      width: 9em;
      /* adjust as needed or use auto */
      padding: 8px;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 1.50em;
      border: 1px dotted #666;
      border-top: none;
      color: #000;
    }
    /**alternating background colors**/
    
    nav li:nth-child(odd) > a {
      background: #CAD3D3
    }
    
    nav li:nth-child(even) > a {
      background: #9BBB59
    }
    /**top menu style on mouse over**/
    
    nav li:hover > a {
      color: #FFF;
      background: #004A43;
    }
    /**sub-menu**/
    
    nav li ul {
      display: none;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 1em;
      background: none;
    }
    /**sub-menu, help for older IE**/
    
    nav li:hover > ul,
    nav li.hover > ul {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    nav li:hover li,
    nav li.hover li {
      float: none;
    }
    /**drop-menu style**/
    
    nav li:hover li a,
    nav li.hover li a {
      width: 9em;
      /* adjust width as needed or use auto */
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    /**drop-menu style on mouse over**/
    
    nav li li a:hover {
      background: #D3E1B7;
      color: #004A43;
    }
    /* Clear floated elements at the end*/
    
    nav:after {
      visibility: hidden;
      display: block;
      font-size: 0;
      content: " ";
      clear: both;
      height: 0;
    }
    /**end Horizontal drop-menus**/
    
    nav ul ul ul {
      left: calc(100% - 12px);
      top: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="demos">
  <div id="content">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="first" href="#">ABOUT US &#9660;</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS &#9660;</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Broken Glass</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mosaic Tiles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Adhesives &#9658;</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sticky</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stickier</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stickiest</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hella Sticky</a></li>
              </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Grout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES &#9660;</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Gloves</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rubber Mallets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sponges</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Safety Glasses</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```